# How to create a bulk load of similar buttons using PS CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

What is a good way of creating a bulk load of buttons using photoshop CS5? They are all the same background, and size, but different overlay text.

Please bear in mind I am new to PS but have an understanding of some of the basics like layers and the toolbox tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have a few buttons, lawndartcatcher's answer is your best bet. If "bulk load" means >10 or so, then here's one alternative. It's more sophisticated, and it does save in a batch, but I wouldn't swear it's significantly quicker.

- Create your text layers over the background. Each bit of text will be on its own layer, and if you have Effects applied, you can replicate the effects by just copying the first text layer and changing the text.
- Now turn on your text layers one at a time and create a Layer Comp (`Window > Layer Comps`) for each one. Be sure that "Visibility" is checked. (Do this *after* you create the text layers, to avoid Photoshop nagging you about the comps being out of date.)

[image: Layer Comp Dialog]

- When you're done, you'll have a set of Layer Comps that include the background and one text layer each.

[image: Layer Comps done]

- Select `File > Scripts > Layer Comps to Files` and pick your file options in the dialog.

[image: Layer Comps to Files dialog]

You'll have a set of individual numbered files that you can use as-is or rename as needed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've answered your own question - create the button elements, create the overlay text (as a separate layer), and use "Save As" to save each individual button as an individual file.

Or are you looking for an automated process?

Comment: I was looking for something a bit more sophisticated, or quicker. perhaps there is a way to save in a batch?